# What is the meaning of "unqualified gain"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of "an unqualified gain" in context of the following sentence?

> For environmental advocates, the increased focus on ecoefficiency (measures to reduce negative environmental impact brought on by businesses processes) might seem `an unqualified gain`. Were these advocates more informed on the possible ramifications of ecoefficient practices, they would likely regard those businesses conforming to ecoefficient standards with measured skepticism. For one, businesses that conform to such standards and become profitable can reinvest this money into industries that are ecoinefficient, or these businesses, if wildly successful, can through sheer scale create more waste than they did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unqualified in the following sense by [M-W:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unqualified)

> : not modified or restricted by reservations, complete.
>
> - *an unqualified denial*.

Comment: How can we surely say that the advocates had complete gain. They were doubtful, correct?

Comment: @DeepakAhire - yes, the article says: “ ...might seem an unqualified gain”, implying that it is probably not.